# Redis performance using hmget

Tags: performance, redis

I want to multi-get value from redis by using hmget in my app, about 1000+ value all at once. But I am afraid it will cause some performance problem. Has anybody tried this before?

Answer (score 2):

Should really not be a problem, as it is O(N) where N is the number of fields being requested. So it is O(1000+) in your case with no roundtrips on network and of course all in RAM.

If you worry it might be too much (but I doubt it, test it if you really need to) or your data can grow to unexpected size (which is really something to be afraid of), you should consider running many smaller queries on the hash with a fixed size, for instance getting field values 1000 by 1000 until you read them all.

It is only to not hit the timeout limit of a redis task (if it is the case your query fails) and to allow redis to better distribute the load (it is monothreaded so no other query can run at the same time).

Comment: Thank you! I will have a try!